# local variable value is not used - python

Tags: python, arcpy

I am writing some python code (to work in conjuction with ArcGIS), and I have a simple statement that runs fine and does exactly what I am asking it to do, I just get a 'warning' from my scripting software (PyCharm) telling me:

- *Local variable 'row' value is not used*
- *This inspection highlights local variables, parameters or local functions unused in scope.*

I understand it is not used, because it is not needed. This is the only way (that I know of personally) to work out how many rows exist in a table.

Can someone tell me if there is a better (more correct) way of writing this??

```
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(my_table)
for row in cursor:
    count += 1
print count
```

Cheers

Comment: Change `for row in cursor` to `for _ in cursor`

Comment: I usually use `sum(1 for row in cursor)`, though I don't know if it'll do anything about the warning. Bhargav's suggestion of naming the unused variable `_` should help.

Comment: You should use arcpy's [Get Count](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000n7000000.htm)

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I didn't realise this 'GetCount_management' was available, I will be modifying my code to use this instead. 
Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By convention if you're looping and don't intend to use the value you store the iterator in a variable named `_`.  This is still a normal variable that gets each value in turn, but is taken to mean "I don't plan to use this value."  To use this convention you'd rewrite your code as:

```
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(my_table)
for _ in cursor:
    count += 1
print count
```

See [What is the purpose of the single underscore "_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) to learn more about the single underscore variable.

But as Markus Meskanen pointed out there is a better way to solve this specific problem.

Comment: Thanks Eric, your suggestion has satisfied the PyCharm formatting checker, it works well. I did not realise until Marcus suggested, but I should be using the ArcPy.GetCount_management() tool instead. Thanks for your time everyone

Comment: Yeah, Markus's suggestion is definitely the way to go here, but this is still good to know as the accepted convention for this situation should it come up again

Comment: You could have explained in a better manner as to what `_` is. :) Nevertheless you have clearly explained the usage. Hence +1 to you

Comment: @BhargavRao I'll happily add to the answer if you think I wasn't clear that `_` is just a variable name like any other that by convention means "I don't plan to use this".

Comment: I have added a small link there. I think this makes the answer complete.